# Observer on a controller property from a route not firing

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to place an observer on a controller property from within a route but the observer never gets fired.

Here is a basic example where the application route has an action that sets a property on a child route's controller. The child route has an observer (`cleanup`) on the controller's property (`controller.isDirty`) which never gets fired. I can't figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujwyvhrp/3/

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('child');
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return true;
    },
    actions: {
        makeDirty: function(){
            this.controllerFor('child').set('isDirty', true);
        }
    }
});

App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return true;
    },
    cleanup: function(){
        this.controller.set('isDirty',false);
    }.observes('controller.isDirty')
});

App.ChildController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isDirty: false
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register your observer in setupController (i. e. after the controller has been instantiated, if necessary), it works.

```
App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return true;
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        this.addObserver('controller.isDirty', function() {
          this.controller.set('isDirty',false);
        });
    }
});
```

This is not a complete solution (you'd have to removeObserver sometime), but hopefully points you into the right direction. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ujwyvhrp/4/

Essentially this is a dirty work around for the unobservability of controller mentioned bei Gaurav. This should work as long as the controller isn't changed (which it should not, because it is treated as a singleton anyway, but it might become a problem if you're doing something unsual).

Comment: This looks like the cleanest way I've seen to get around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'controller' property in a route is not observable. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9370